# Rx merge operator and parallel execution

Tags: system.reactive, rx.net

Why does the `.Merge` operator behave like `.Synchronize`?

I have two streams of events, each emitting values in different threads (for example using `Observable.Interval`).

After using the `.Merge` operator they lock each other in long operator (with only one operation running in parallel after merging, like in a `.Synchronize()` operation). Why is this?

```
var xs1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Select(x => $"xs1 : {x}").Log("xs1 generating");
var xs2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Select(x => $"xs1 : {x}").Log("xs2 generating");

xs1.Merge(xs2)
        .Do(x=> Thread.Sleep(2_000))
        .SubscribeConsoleWithThreads("after long work");
```

produces these results:

```
13:44:14 thread 4 xs1 generating : "xs1 : 0"
13:44:14 thread 5 xs2 generating : "xs2 : 0"
13:44:16 thread 4 after long work: "xs1 : 0"
13:44:16 thread 4 xs1 generating : "xs1 : 1"
13:44:18 thread 5 after long work: "xs2 : 0"
13:44:18 thread 5 xs2 generating : "xs2 : 1"
13:44:20 thread 4 after long work: "xs1 : 1"
13:44:20 thread 4 xs1 generating : "xs1 : 2"
```

As you see values "xs1 : 0" and "xs2 : 0" are generated in parallel from both streams, but after that, they are generated one by one.

Can merging to one Observable be made without locking parallel execution?

Comment: Can you post the code for `.Log` and `.SubscribeConsoleWithThreads`?

Comment: `public static IObservable<T> Log<T>(this IObservable<T> self, String prefix)
  {
   return self.Do(x =>
   {
    Console.WriteLine(
     $"{DateTime.Now:T} thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {prefix} : {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)}");
   });
  }`

Comment: `public static void SubscribeConsoleWithThreads<T>(this IObservable<T> self, String prefix = "")
  {
   self
    .Subscribe(obj =>
     {
      Console.WriteLine(
       $"{DateTime.Now:T} thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {prefix}: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)}");
     });
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the contract for Rx. Produce zero or more values, **one at a time**, and optionally end with either a single `OnError` or a single `OnCompleted`.

The `.Synchronize()` operator is there to enforce a non-compliant observable to be compliant.

Calling `xs1.Merge(xs2)` doesn't "lock parallel execution". The execution of the two sources are independent of each other. Rx just ensures that values are output one at a time so that there is no concurrency issues.

The issue with your code is the computation after the merge. If you do your work before the merge life is then better.

Compare these:

```
var xs1 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(x => new { source = 1, value = x })
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, generated = x.Timestamp });

var xs2 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(x => new { source = 2, value = x })
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, generated = x.Timestamp });

xs1.Merge(xs2)
        .Do(x=> Thread.Sleep(2_000))
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, x.Value.generated, output = x.Timestamp })
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.source}: {x.value} - {x.generated.ToString("ss.fff")} - {x.output.ToString("ss.fff")}"));
```

This produces:

```
1: 0 - 18.875 - 20.877
2: 0 - 18.884 - 22.882
1: 1 - 20.881 - 24.883
2: 1 - 22.882 - 26.884
1: 2 - 24.883 - 28.884
2: 2 - 26.884 - 30.884
1: 3 - 28.884 - 32.886
2: 3 - 30.884 - 34.887
1: 4 - 32.886 - 36.887
2: 4 - 34.887 - 38.887
```

And then this:

```
var xs1 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(x => new { source = 1, value = x })
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, generated = x.Timestamp })
        .Do(x=> Thread.Sleep(2_000));

var xs2 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(x => new { source = 2, value = x })
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, generated = x.Timestamp })
        .Do(x=> Thread.Sleep(2_000));

xs1.Merge(xs2)
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(x => new { x.Value.source, x.Value.value, x.Value.generated, output = x.Timestamp })
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.source}: {x.value} - {x.generated.ToString("ss.fff")} - {x.output.ToString("ss.fff")}"));
```

That gives:

```
1: 0 - 29.178 - 31.182
2: 0 - 29.180 - 31.201
1: 1 - 31.201 - 33.202
2: 1 - 31.201 - 33.202
2: 2 - 33.202 - 35.203
1: 2 - 33.202 - 35.203
1: 3 - 35.203 - 37.204
2: 3 - 35.203 - 37.204
1: 4 - 37.204 - 39.205
2: 4 - 37.204 - 39.205
```

That's doubled the output speed of the observable.